# How can people cancel their membership?

Tags: civimember

We have a membership type that auto-renews every month. People pay via Authorize.net, Paypal, or they give us their info from their check and an automated draft is created over via Authorize.net.

However, I can't find a way to tell people how to go about ending their own membership other than contacting the organization and having them do it for the person.

How do people go about ending their membership on their own?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Drupal, you could set up a webform that allows people to change their membership status. This would not require any custom code, the functionality is all there in the Webform-CiviCRM module. You'd just want to carefully select which membership statuses you want to allow people to give themselves by editing that field and deselecting inappropriate options after adding it to the form.

Answer (score 1):

Member cannot end his own membership on his own - it's bit tricky

**But can be achieved by** 
provide an option in the contact dashboard with an button to end his own membership - to achieve this you need to write an extension